# Passing arguments to another variadic function

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, c++17, ellipsis, variadic

Is there any way at all for this code to compile and work as intended without resorting to `va_list` stuff ?

```
#include <iostream>

void fct(void)
{
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void fct(int index, int indexes...)
{
    std::cout << index << ' ';
    fct(indexes); //or fct(indexes...); ?
}

int main(void)
{
    fct(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you considered making `fct` a variadic template function?

Comment: How would that solve my problem? Would this not uselessly complicate things? What I'm trying to achieve seems very simple so far.

Comment: The truth is, I can't use variadic templates here because I already do. The above code is very simplified to get to the core of my problem, but the real code I'm working on has an std::size_t variadic template. I would like to solve this problem without templates.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Why can't you make this a template?

Comment: @cantordust I've presented my problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50307095/passing-variadic-parameters-in-an-already-template-variadic-function

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you have misunderstood the meaning of the signature

```
void fct (int index, int indexes...)
```

I suspect you think that `fct()` expect a `int` single value (`index`) and a variadic list of `int`'s (`indexex...`) with C++11 style of parameter pack expansion.

No: [it's the same as](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments)

```
void fct (int index, int indexes, ...)
```

so **two** `int` single values and a C-style of optional argument that you can use only through `va_list` stuff.

If you don't believe it, try calling `fct()` with only an integer argument

```
fct(1);
```

You should obtain an error of type "error: no matching function for call to 'fct'" with a note of type "note: candidate function not viable: requires at least 2 arguments, but 1 was provided" regarding the variadic version of `fct()`.

If you want receive a variadic list of parameters and recursively pass the to the same function, you can use the template variadic way.

By example

```
template <typename ... Ts>
void fct(int index, Ts ... indexes)
{
    std::cout << index << ' ';
    fct(indexes...);
}
```

Comment: And maybe throw in a `void fct(){ std::cout << std::endl; }` to print the `endl`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In other words, there is absolutely no way to solve this issue without templates and `va_list` :\

Comment: @Pippin - No, as far I know. Or better: the way (starting from C++11) is the variadic template one. I don't understand what's wrong, for you, with the variadic template way.

Comment: @max66 I've presented my problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50307095/passing-variadic-parameters-in-an-already-template-variadic-function

Comment: @Pippin - as you can see in my answer  in the new question, the use of variadic templates is extremely simple.

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* dislike the idea of a template, I guess you could cheat a bit like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void fct(std::vector<int>&& _indices)
{
    for (auto&& i : _indices)
    {
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main(void)
{
    fct({1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}); // Note the curly braces
    return 0;
}
```